# RealmObject Equatable redundant message

Tags: swift, realm, equatable

We have a simple class `Person` which inherent from realms `Object`. 
Now we want that subclass to conform to the `Equatable` protocol. The very simple code looks like this.

```
class Person: Object, Equatable {

    dynamic var localID     = "0"
    dynamic var name:String?
}

func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {

    return lhs.localID == rhs.localID
}
```

We started with realm version 0.98.8 and everything worked as aspected. When we updated to version 0.102.0 (and the other versions between) the complier error message occurs

```
Error: Redundant conformance of ‚Person‘ to protocol ‚Equatable‘
```

Not strange enough, if downgrade back to version 0.98.8 the error still remains. Another strange behavior, on one of our developers machine, the same code compiles just fine.

After some research we have no idea what is going on and how to fix or workaround this.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue! Thanks for posting this question. I was getting redundant conformance from implementing Hashable. Some of my teammates were fine and others were getting the Error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Latest version of `RealmSwift` implements `Equatable` by default, you can look at `Object.swift` from `RealmSwift` code.

To override default `Equatable` behaviour, you can override this function:

```
public override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool
```

After that, existing Swift code with `==` will return result based on custom condition defined inside `isEqual`. No need to create `func ==` manually.

It's still using `isEqual` due to `RLMObjectBase` subclassed from `NSObject`, not pure Swift object.

Answer (score 4):

The updated signature for Swift 4 is:

```
open override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `RealmSwift`, `Object` is already conforming to `Equatable`. So you don't have to add the  `Equatable` in the definition of `Person`.

[But you do not seem to be the only one having problems with this.](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2519)

Comment: This was our fist suggestion. But if we remove the Equatable protocol from the Person class, the equatable check never get called. Also the Realm Object  inherits from RLMObjectBase and RLMObjectBase from NSObject. There is no conformance to the Equatable at all